# What's the point of passing a lambda to a decorator without real needs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I first saw this kind of coding style in TypeORM, it didn't bring me too much attention back then since I didn't use it. However, I've been seeing a lot of them lately, and I don't get it, what's the point to do that? Plus if I turn on `noUnusedParameters` in **tsconfig**, this syntax will definitely break the compilation.

```
@someDecorator(of => SomeType)
class SomeClass {
    // ...
}
```